# Cannot remove folder redirection

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008, group-policy

I enabled folder redirection for a single account to test it out and see how I liked working with it on a day-to-day basis. After some testing, I realized it won't work in my environment and thus decided to remove it. Every redirected folder had the option to re-direct to the local profile setting if the policy was removed checked.

I first tried removing the user from the security filter, but that did not work. `gpresult` showed when I logged in that the policy was gone, but all documents were still on a remote location.

I then re-added the user and deleted the link. This time it took a few minutes to log on, which I assumed meant it was copying files...but alas, the same result when I finally logged in.

I then re-added the link to restore it to the original state and proceeded to delete the GPO itself. Same result.

How in the world can you remove folder redirection, short of deleting the user entirely which isn't really a good option? Using Server 2008, client machine is Windows 7.